# Cannot get "debug test" to work in VSCode (golang)

Tags: go, debugging, testing, visual-studio-code

Debugging tests to work perfectly but at some point recently something changed, and now it doesn't (perhaps a go version upgrade?).

[image: debug test image]

When I click "debug test" this error message pops up:

[image: Failed to launch: invalid debug configuration - cannot unmarshal bool into "env" of type string]

The error is: `Failed to launch: invalid debug configuration - cannot unmarshal bool into "env" of type string`

My `launch.json` seems fine (again, this used to work perfectly):

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch test function",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "test",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "env": {
            "LOG_LEVEL": "debug",
            "LOG_SQL": "false",
            "DATABASE_URL": "postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/chainlink_test?sslmode=disable",
        },
        "args": ["-v"]
    },
]
```

}

What could be wrong?

Comment: Some boolean type value was sent to dlv and dlv was unhappy about it. :-(

Can you enable the logging and see what `launch` command request is sent? In your launch.json config: add the following.

```
            "showLog": true,
            "logOutput": "dap"
```
From my local testing, I saw all the three env vars encoded as string key/value types correctly. So, I guess there are some other env vars inherited.

Comment: This just happened after upgrading to 1.18 as well.

Comment: {
  "seq": 2,
  "type": "request",
  "command": "launch",
  "arguments": {
    "name": "Launch test package",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "program": ".",
    "showLog": true,
    "logOutput": "dap",
    "env": {
      "GOPATH": "xxx",
      "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD": "xxx"
    },
    "__configurationTarget": 5,
    "packagePathToGoModPathMap": {
      ...
    },
    "debugAdapter": "dlv-dap",
    "showRegisters": false,
    "showGlobalVariables": false,
    "hideSystemGoroutines": false
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I have `CGO_ENABLED=0` in my global config. However, something is overriding and now expecting a String instead. Try something like this in your launch.json:

```
{
  [...]
  "env": {[...] "CGO_ENABLED": "0" [...]},
  [...]
},
```

Comment: I had a setting like this in my user `settings.json`, under `go.toolsEnvVars`. Sneaky.

Comment: I had a setting in my workspace `settings.json` under `go.testEnvVars` that was setting an env variable to a number. Look in your settings files for an env that is being set to a non-string.

`"go.testEnvVars": { "DB_PORT": 5444 }` and 
convert to string `"DB_PORT": "5444"`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but is it because “LOG_SQL” is “false” instead of false (string vs bool), and it’s trying to parse “false” to bool.

Comment: I changed it the other way around, from `false` to `"false"` and the message went away. But now nothing is being executed :/

Answer (score 0):

```
Have the same issue. Did solve by 
1. added line  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/server.env" to launch.json
2. added file server.env into ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/ with following content:
    LOG_LEVEL=debug 
    LOG_SQL=false
    DATABASE_URL=...
3. And removed env section from launch.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turns out it was because of a key/value pair in my settings.json where the value was a number. I turned it into a string and it worked fine. I though VS code only used the launch.json when debugging, but I guess not.